# Why does YoutubePlayerView stops every 2 second

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-api

On button click Video starts successfully but, pauses every one second , what might be the problem ? youtubeplayer loadvideo is only called one time it must play the video without interuptions ...

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
    mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("W4hTJybfU7s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            youtubePlayerView.initialize(PlayerConfig.getApiKey(),mOnInitializedListener);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's hard to tell what's going on due to missing information (check the logcat, It may have some usefull information)

BUT

If I had to take a bet, I would say that, in your layout, It may have another view overlapping your Youtube player.

Youtube view needs to be visible to the user while video is played. If you have another view (or even a tiny slice if it) overlapping youtube player, the player will present this pause behaviour.

It doesn't matter which kind of view or even if it's invisible/colorless. Youtube player can't have any view overlapping it